# How much can the 95th Percentile lift without overly exerting themselves?

Tags: strength, weights

In terms of product design how large a weight could people in the 95th Percentile (Men & Women) lift in KG, per hand, without overly exerting themselves? This is in regards to anthropometrics, and the data would be used with 95th percentile hand sizes, etc.

As for defining overly exerting themselves, I'd say in terms of being able to hold an object for a prolonged period of time, without showing any noticeable signs in terms of biology that they were doing this, e.g. Sweating, Feeling Uncomfortable. For example, a phone is below this lift, a normal television is above.

Comment: 95th percentile...of what?

Comment: 95th percentile of height? weight? squat strength?

Comment: 95th percentile means that only 5% of the population (extreme) wouldn't be able to lift it. It's like saying how much does the average person weigh, but for product design that isn't good as you still alienate part of the market, so you want a figure that would be suitable for most people. E.g. If the figure for lifting was say 15kg, there might be 5% of the population that are really unfit and couldn't manage that, but for 95% of the population it'd be ok.

Comment: I think this isn't really a question, because its vague and overly broad. I don't think it can be reasonably answered in its current form, so I have closed it. If you update your question to make it more specific, it can always be reopened

Answer (score 0):

I like this question. If you're trying to create metrics for this, you should look up records - records of feats that measure the parameters you're looking for. For example if you found the record for bench press, you could consultant a physicist to see how much force,power, etc is required to complete the lift, and then figure out where you want your 95% percentile to be if that record is the 100% level.

Here are the records fr wieght lifting
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_world_records_in_Olympic_weightlifting

As for this 95% cuttoff. Maybe you shoudl base it on the worlds population. As in, it's the amount that no LESS than 5% of the worlds population could lift without the fatigue aspects you mentioned before.

Answer (score -1):

Through what i see from those gym i normally go, 20-30 kg dumbell are most commonly use by those weight lifter who want to have nice body. Those intense body builder will be pushing much more heavier example i once saw a guy pushng 50kg dumbell for his dumbell press.
that is for dumbell press as i do not what type of exercise u are looking for.

Comment: I lift 50kg dumb bells and I'm not that big.